# how to define TaskKey which handle scope relative information in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT has a power Scope concept to handle different key values in different condition.

But I'm not really grasp how to get scope relative key values, for example, there is a `build.sbt` where I want print different values of `keyTest` in different project scope:

```
name := "sbttest"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

lazy val keyTest = taskKey[Unit]("keyTest")
lazy val settingTest = settingKey[String]("settingTest")

settingTest := "init setting"
keyTest := {
  val currentProjectName = name.value
  val currentSettingTest = settingTest.value
  println("currentProjectName: " + currentProjectName)
  println("currentSettingTest: " + currentSettingTest)
}

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "projRoot",
    settingTest := "setting_root"
  )

lazy val projA = (project in file("projA"))
  .settings(
    name := "projA",
    settingTest := "setting_A"
  )
```

As a result in sbt:

```
> ;project root;keyTest
 currentProjectName: sbttest
 currentSettingTest: init setting

> ;project projA;keyTest
[error] Not a valid command: testKey
[error] Not a valid project ID: testKey
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: testKey (similar: test, testOnly, testFilter)
[error] testKey
[error]        ^
```

how to print this result which is distinct with `root` and `projA` project as this?

```
   > ;project root;keyTest
   currentProjectName: projRoot
   currentSettingTest: setting_root

   > ;project projA;keyTest
   currentProjectName: projA
   currentSettingTest: setting_A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, top-level *expressions* in `build.sbt` are evaluated under the root project scope. The easiest way to use common settings across multiple projects is to create a sequence of those settings and call `.settings` method with the sequence on each project. For example, your `build.sbt` will look like:

```
val keyTest = taskKey[Unit]("keyTest")
val settingTest = settingKey[String]("settingTest")

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.4",

  keyTest := {
    val currentProjectName = name.value
    val currentSettingTest = settingTest.value
    println("currentProjectName: " + currentProjectName)
    println("currentSettingTest: " + currentSettingTest)
  }
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    name := "projRoot",
    settingTest := "setting_root"
  )

lazy val projA = (project in file("projA"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    name := "projA",
    settingTest := "setting_A"
  )
```

```
sbt:projRoot> sbtVersion
[info] 1.1.1

sbt:projRoot> root / keyTest
currentProjectName: projRoot
currentSettingTest: setting_root
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 17, 2018 11:35:27 AM

sbt:projRoot> projA / keyTest
currentProjectName: projA
currentSettingTest: setting_A
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 17, 2018 11:35:36 AM
```